# Alternative ways to say "after something"

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, alternatives

In describing an algorithm, I feel I repeatedly use "*After doing this, the algorithm do that*". I look for alternative ways to say such sequences. For example I wrote:

> After obtaining the Post-Matches rules, the algorithm performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches

I think of writing it as:

> Once the Post-Matches rules were obtained, the algorithm performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches.

Are they equivalent? What are other ways to say such sentences?

Comment: Is your question whether these have the same meaning?  They look the same to me, though in the second sentence "were obtained" should be "are obtained," since the tense should be consistent.

Comment: @cbh yes, and any other way to say that.

Comment: As a matter of style, I prefer the first version. I try to avoid the passive voice if the subject is known.

Comment: I presume you are using an intro clause like "After obtaining the Post-Matches rules" because *obtaining the Post-Matches rules* was not the previous step. If it was, why not just use *Then* instead. You really need to tell us what came before your quote.

Comment: What about "Having obtained the Post-Matches rules..."?

Comment: @JMB Thanks, seems good! I also think of "At the next stage,"

Comment: @user3169 *Then* is also good, but I feel I explained a long paragraph for the previous step, then I thought maybe "Then" is not appropriate, because the user may not found "After what", or where is the "First"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid repeating "after something" you can use these variants:

- When the Post-Matches rules are obtained, the algorithm then performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches.
- Once the Post-Matches rules are obtained, the algorithm performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches.
- Having obtained the Post-Matches rules, the algorithm performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches.
- As soon as the Post-Matches rules are obtained, the algorithm performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches.
- The instant (moment,second) the Post-Matches rules are obtained, the algorithm performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches.

You can add a few more words:

- After having successfully obtained the Post-Matches rules, the algorithm performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches.
- Immediately (directly, right, shortly, soon, just) after obtaining the Post-Matches rules, the algorithm performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches.
- Subsequent to the obtaining of the Post-Matches rules, the algorithm performs the extraction command and the post-assignments of both Pre-Matches and Post-Matches.